# Non-hyperbolic zeros of vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I'm wondering the following:

Let $V$ be a vector field on a (compact Riemannian) smooth manifold $M$ with non-degenerate zeros. Let $p$ be a non-hyperbolic zero of $V$. Can we perturb $V$ slightly so that $p$ becomes hyperbolic while the sign of the index of $p$ remains unchanged?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you have a non-hyperbolic zero, perturbation of vector field might create new equilibria out of the old one. The index of original equilibria will be equal to the sum of indexes of all appeared equilibria for small perturbations. And I think that's the key: if you had an equilibrium with non-zero index (say, positive), it's impossible for all new equilibria to have negative index.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know of any resources where I might learn more about this (or that gives the relevant background theory to deduce this)?

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at most relevant entries at Scholarpedia :) I don't really remember in which English book the homotopy invariance of index has been covered.